# Custom Template tags only evaluate when put inside another block

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a custom tag with classytag

```
class GetLanguage(Tag):
    name = 'GetLanguage'
    options = Options(
        Argument('name', resolve=False)
    )

    def render_tag(self, context, name):
        raise  #I put raise here to see if it run the code?
        return name

register.tag(GetLanguage)
```

and a base.html template

```
{% block myblock %}{% endblock %}
blah blah
```

and a index.html template

```
{% extend base.html %}
{% block myblock %}{% endblock %}
```

If i put my tag in index.html (not in any block)

```
{% GetLanguage %}
{% block myblock %}{% endblock %}
```

nothing happend. but if i put in base.html it's work. Then if i move code in to a block in index.html it's also work.

```
{% block myblock %}{% GetLanguage %}{% endblock %}
```

Why?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077050/django-templatetag-scope-forcing-me-to-do-extra-queries

Comment: How can I thank you @AamirAdnan